# What grants are needed for the SQL Server Telegraf plugin in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, telegraf

I'm using the Telegraf input plugin for SQL Server (https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/sqlserver) to gather metrics and report to InfluxDB. It works well for SQL Server, but though it supports Azure SQL Database the documentation is a bit sparse.

The database user should be created like this:

```
CREATE LOGIN [telegraf] WITH PASSWORD = N'password';
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO [telegraf];
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO [telegraf];
```

That works on SQL Server, but in Azure it fails:

> Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server.

I wonder what I need to grant instead in order to solve this in the best possible way. We have a large number of databases running on the same server in an elastic pool, so if it is possible I would like to use a single user that logs in to the master and collects metrics for all the databases at once (the way it works with SQL Server). If that is impossible I can configure multiple logins and process one database at a time.

Perhaps I can grant `VIEW DEFINITION` at the database level, but `VIEW SERVER STATE` does not seem to be supported at all.

So, how should I configure the SQL Database login(s) for Telegraf with the SQL Server plugin to make it work?

EDIT:

- Running as the super user for the server works without errors, but only produces metrics for master and tempdb. I need metrics for the many application databases and they are missing. Plus running as the super user is less than ideal.
- Running as the super user for the server but connecting to a specific application database (add database in connection string) crashes with a nil pointer dereference and the log complains about VIEW DATABASE STATE permission denied in database master (the super user has access, but apparently not when connecting to a spefic database).
- Granting VIEW DATABASE and VIEW DEFINITION to telegraf in an application database and connecting directly to that database as telegraf crashes with a nil pointer dereference and the log says the connection was closed.

EDIT 2:

Created bug report https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/4222.

EDIT 3:

As of the latest release the plugin works if the server admin account is used, so the issue has been solved. There is still no way to run with a less privileged account in Azure DB.

Answer (score 3):

**The answer:** 
`GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE` is not supported in Azure SQL Database.

> On SQL Database Premium Tiers requires the VIEW DATABASE STATE
>   permission in the database. Permissions can not be granted in Master,
>   but the views can be queried in user databases. On SQL Database
>   Standard and Basic Tiers requires the SQL Database server admin
>   account due to security requirements following from multi tenancy of
>   those tiers.

**Reason:** 
SQL Azure SQL is PaaS solution, therefore the most "server" specific features, DMVs, settings are blocked by purpose

**References:**

[Grant View Server State - is it possible for a none SA user to have in Azure SQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189359/grant-view-server-state-is-it-possible-for-a-none-sa-user-to-have-in-azure-sql)

[SQL Azure VIEW DATABASE STATE permission denied in database 'master'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31218872/sql-azure-view-database-state-permission-denied-in-database-master)

**Possible workaround:** (which is, anyway does not work in ewramner case)

```
CREATE LOGIN [telegraf] WITH PASSWORD = N'password';

USE [yourDB]
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [telegraf];
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO [telegraf];
```

Therefore,  (IMHO), there is no way to make such application working in SQL Azure without changing application code

Comment: That is true, but the application (Telegraf sqlserver plugin) has already been changed and should support Azure. There is a specific option for it (azuredb = true). Presumably that has been tested and works, but they have not documented how to setup the user.

Comment: @ewramner,  what is the current database tier in use? 
I've checked a source code of the  tool and indeed, it supports Azure SQL, but special parameter to be used - "azuredb = true." 

It relies on a DMV sys.dm_db_resource_stats and such DMV requires "VIEW DATABASE STATE" permissions, which you already have tried

Comment: It is standard tier. You can see the Azure CLI commands (slightly edited) in the linked issue. The parameter is set to true.

Comment: Since you have a standard tier, you can run that application using a "server admin" login. In your case required permissions cannot be granted to login [telegraf]. Next to that, you cannot create another Server admin account, or rename existing  one

Comment: I see what you mean. Nasty considering the price difference. I'll see if I can test on premium. Still, this fails even with the server admin account, or at least it shows data only for master/tempdb and not for the application databases.

Comment: Unfortunately premium doesn't help. See linked issue for details, but in essence it behaves more or less like standard. Same errors.

Comment: With the latest telegraf release running as server admin works, though I really don't like using that account from a monitoring agent.